# Is it possible to autoformat / beautify SQL queries using pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, code-formatting, pgadmin-4

I would like to autoformat / beautify my SQL-queries directly in [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/). I know this feature from Java-developing in Eclipse, where I can beautify the whole code using a simple shortcut.

I only found a command line solution so far that makes my SQL queries pretty: [pgFormatter](https://github.com/darold/pgFormatter).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently this feature is not implemented in pgadmin4 which does autoformat or beautify SQL-queries automatically but you can expect this feature in near future version as developers are working on this feature.

Developers discussion mail thread for the feature:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAPG3WN46pgzxKERPpr4TSpVFtyeMhParjvKAUzXWOuwZ4qJPhg@mail.gmail.com

Comment: The answer is outdated.

Answer (score 64):

Try the following command:

```
shift+Ctrl+k
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the context of this answer is so many years later, but this doesn't appear to have any effect in pgAdmin 4.

Comment: Actually thats incorrect, it does in-fact format for me using pgadmin 4.4, in chrome on windows 10

Comment: works but formats it really badly. Its more readable when this command is not used

Comment: also this breaks jsonb constructions

Comment: It seems there's no way to revert to the default formatting configuration, so be cautions if you start tweaking it - you might get weird(er) results and not be able to easily revert those changed.

Answer (score 15):

In pgAdmin5 on macOS this can be done using `Shift + Cmd + K`.

Here is where you can find it in the UI:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Still not implemented afaict, but an option would be to use some online tool.

I've successfully used: https://sqlformat.org/

Answer (score 1):

> Try Shift Shift + ctrl + k

You can use command + Shift + k for SQL code format or beautify.